# Javascript / JQuery "onclick" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why isn't this working? I can't figure it out.

In case it matters, the HTML was injected into a div using jQuery's .append() method.

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#changeInfo").on("click", function() {
    $("#changeInfo").replaceWith('<div id=changeInfo"><div id="changeInfoTrue">Changing login information: </div>'); 
    $("#changeInfoTrue").append('<br><b>Username: <input type="text" name="newUsername" onkeypress = "checkLength()" id="newUsername" /><br> Password:&nbsp; <input type="password" name="newPassword" id="newPassword" onkeypress = "checkLength()" /></b>&nbsp;<input type="button" onclick="buttonPress();" value="Go!" id="goButton" /></div>'); 
  }); 
  function buttonPress() { 
    $("#changeInfo").replaceWith('Your login information has been reset.');
  }
});
```

Comment: Missing `)` of `replaceWith`. Other than that if the problem still persists, check if the element `$("#changeInfo")` exists.

Comment: Fixed, it still doesn't work. `changeInfo` definitely exists...

Comment: Use alert inside your buttonPress() function to debug.

Comment: Show `changeInfo` element please.

Comment: remove the `;` from the onclick for starters,  might fix it,  might not, but it's not needed there. but add an alert to make sure it's at least firing your function.   if that works we can then look to see why it's not changing the value (and we'll need you to post the `#changeinfo` object as well

Comment: `buttonPress` is _private_ function of `ready` callback, it cannot be accessed from outside of it(including HTML onclick), move the function outside of `ready` callback

Comment: alert() in buttonPress() doesn't work - the function isn't executing.

Answer (score 0):

Add Jquery Libery

Jquery Function

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
  $("#changeInfo").on("click", function() {
    $("#changeInfo").replaceWith('<div id=changeInfo"><div id="changeInfoTrue">Changing login information: </div>'); 
    $("#changeInfoTrue").append('<br><b>Username: <input type="text" name="newUsername" onkeypress = "checkLength()" id="newUsername" /><br> Password:&nbsp; <input type="password" name="newPassword" id="newPassword" onkeypress = "checkLength()" /></b>&nbsp;<input type="button" onclick="buttonPress();" value="Go!" id="goButton" /></div>'); 
  }); 
  function buttonPress() { 
    $("#changeInfo").replaceWith('Your login information has been reset.');
  }
});
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="" id="changeInfo">Click here</div
```

Demo Link : https://jsfiddle.net/tw79mvau/1/